# Make executable symbolic link in Python?

Tags: python, bash, bin

I have a file called `client.py`. I created a symbolic link called `incro` using

```
ln -s client.py incro
```

How do I make this script executable and move it to my bin (I'm on Linux using Ubuntu, with a bash terminal), under the name of `incro`? So that I will be able to run

```
incro
```

I have the proper sha-bang. What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the link in your `bin` directory, not the current directory:

```
ln -s $PWD/client.py ~/bin/incro
```

You should also have `~/bin` in your `$PATH` so that you can run programs that are in there.

And if the script isn't already executable, add that:

```
chmod +x client.py
```

Comment: `ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/home/ubuntu/bin/incro’: No such file or directory`

Comment: You need to create the `bin` directory first.

Comment: Ok, never mind about that. I ran `ln -s client.py incro` and then moved `incro` to `/usr/local/bin`. I then ran `incro` and it said the command didn't exist. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you put a relative pathname in a symbolic link, it's interpreted relative to the directory that contains the link. So when you moved `incro` to `/usr/local/bin`, it became a link to `/usr/local/bin/client.py`, which doesn't exist. That's why my answer creates an absolute pathname with `$PWD`.

Comment: `python: can't open file '/usr/local/bin/incro': [Errno 13] Permission denied`

Answer (score 1):

In Linux to make a file executable you will need to set the file with the following command:

```
chmod +x [filename]
```

This will make the file executable to root, user, and group owners.

To make the file executable from any directory you will need to make sure that the directory is listed in your PATH.

```
echo $PATH
```

will show you which path you should move your file or symbolic link to. There are also ways to add any path to the PATH but you will likely find convention to add your executables to /usr/local/bin. Just validate that it is in your path using the command above.

Comment: This is not solving the whole question.

Comment: I edited the answer. Please let me know if there is still something I am missing you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

By default symbolic links follow file permissions so you don't make symbolic link executable, but simply make your client.py file executable.

Command:

```
ln -s client.py incro
```

Creates relative symbolic link so you can't simply copy or move it to other directory.
To make link movable create link to file with absolute path. For example:

```
ln -s /home/guest/client.py incro
```

Or simply create link directly in your `bin` directory.

Answer (score 0):

in your ~/.bashprofile ,add the line as "alias incro=/path/to/clientfile.py"